# incorrect date set with setDate in jquery ui calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have a weird situation with jquery ui calendar's setDate.

I have two date pickers - checkin and check out.

```
$("#checkin").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(date,dateObj){

        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        selectedDate.setDate( selectedDate.getDate() + 1 );

        $("#checkout").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);


    }
});
```

let's say I have selected 6/1/2011, then checkout date should be 6/2/2011, but I get 6/7/2011.

Do I have an error within my code or is this a bug?

Comment: with which browser are you experiencing that? as i only seem to be able to select the current date with your code

Comment: acroos all the major browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rt3nC/8/

Comment: // thank you for the testing..weird...It works on jsfiddle..so..there must be an error within my code..I will look at it.

Comment: @Moon no problemo, i hope you get it fixed